# "Service unavailable" error in sendmail under linux

Tags: ubuntu, sendmail

My sendmail server occasionally fails at delivering an email. I get a Service unavailable error:

```
Feb  7 23:45:01 ip-10-101-xx-xx sm-mta[3838]: q17Nj0RQ003836: to=<xxxx@xxx.edu>, ctladdr=<www-data@ip-xxxxx.ec2.internal> (33/33), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=esmtp, pri=121203, relay=smtp.xxxx.xxxx.edu. [144.92.xx.xx], dsn=5.0.0, stat=Service unavailable
```

My question is how can I tell if the service at my end was down or the service at the recipient? If it's my problem, how can I solve it?

I'm asking because I'm getting a lot of these errors lately...

Comment: Are there more logs available?

Comment: Send us the output of `grep q17Nj0RQ003836 /var/log/mail.log`

Answer (score 1):

From your log line:
relay=smtp.xxxx.xxxx.edu. [144.92.xx.xx]

That remote server returned a permanent (500) SMTP error code, and so your server will generate a bounce (a Delivery Status Notification). It would be interesting to see what the actual error on the remote server was - usually Sendmail gives a more informative error message and DSN= number.